# Reading table from a crude text file in R

Tags: r, text, import

I have a text file with few first few lines not required and then there is a table which is like this

-Hyphen line-
|  col1 |    col2                    | col3  col4   col5  |
-Hyphen line-
|   1   | 2:24:21 PM 3/22/2012       | 0      0      1    |
|   2   | 2:24:21 PM 3/22/2012       | 1      ·      0    |

1. Col1, Col2 are separated by | but col3,col4 and col5 are just separated by space.
2. Data Type should be maintained like col2 date and col3,4,5 as number ?
3. Row 2, Col4 is dot and so it should be read ad NA
4. Hyphen lines starts and end with - - -

Question:
1. I can use scan, but how to avoid reading "|" and "-" ?
2. I can skip top few lines but how to skip say 50th lines in addition to top few lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read it as a table as-is, then split up the column and recombine.

```
txt <- "| col1 | col2 | col3 col4 col5 |
| 1 | 2:24:21 PM 3/22/2012 | 0 0 1 |
| 2 | 2:24:21 PM 3/22/2012 | 1 · 0 |"

x <- read.table(text = txt, sep = "|", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## drop unnecessary columns from the original sep split
x <- x[,-c(1,ncol(x))]

## split the desired column by the spaces, result is a character matrix
## including an unnecessary first column
split.col3 <- do.call("rbind", strsplit(x[,3], " "))

## bind to the original, dropping the unneeded columns
cbind(x[,-3], split.col3[,-1])
  col1                   col2 1 2 3
1    1  2:24:21 PM 3/22/2012  0 0 1
2    2  2:24:21 PM 3/22/2012  1 · 0
```

I avoided referring to the original column names, since you said you want to skip those lines. Simply add `header = FALSE` and `skip = 50` to the `read.table` call, then add whatever column names make sense afterwards.

Also, you can then strip the "." from columns where necessary, convert to date-time formats or numbers as required. Use `colClasses` in read.table if you know them up front. It makes sense to me to break this down into a number of steps, rather than trying to do it all with one read function.

Comment: ...and `comment.char="-"` in `read.table` should skip any other hyphen lines in your data.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done in three steps. (1) Read in the file all in using `"|"` as the separator, (2) create a new file with just the three columns (contained as one), (3) then read those back in using the space separator. The following code should get you most of the way. Changes that may be required: file names, `V4` column name, and navigating to the proper directory ([`getwd/setwd`](http://rfunction.com/blog/archives/1001)).

```
a <- read.delim("a.txt", FALSE, sep="|")
write.table(a$V4, file="b.txt", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
b <- read.delim("b.txt", FALSE, sep=" ")
```

Merge the appropriate columns of `a` and `b` and then you're done.